# merge two video and make one of them smaller

Tags: software-recommendation, video, video-editor, kdenlive, openshot

I want to prepare a presentation. I captured the screen by **kazam** software and also my face via webcam by **cheeze**  software, so what I have are two mp4 videos.Now I want to merge them. I want to make the video which is include my face, **smaller** and **add that to the top right** of the another video which captured my power point.Searching for some video editors on linux but I do not know which one have this ability?For example openshot does not have this abiliy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you using Kdenlive. you can get if from software center.

here is a video that will help you make the video.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aEu27QCQUb8

take a look at this article

http://en.flossmanuals.net/how-to-use-video-editing-software/multitrack-editing/

This forum post might give you a bit more information

http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=265&t=115507